# How to render a green screen video with transparent background?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

I'm just wondering how to render out an image sequence with no background.

The image appears perfectly right in the viewer node of the compositing layout and it also appears perfectly right in the "image editor".

In render properties I've ticked transparent in the film properties.

In the Output properties I've set the file format to PNG and color to RGBA.

If I set the "Image Editor" to "Viewer Node" I see the output I want, but, if I set it to "Render result" it still has the chroma green back ground.

*My question is* : **How can I render out what I see in the "Viewer Node" with alpha cutting out the chroma green?**

[image: Screen shot of project]

Comment: so if the question is about removing the green background maybe notice it in your title?

Comment: here are 2 tutos on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ3Fc-z4bKM   ...   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZpGpfQjzJA

Comment: Hello :). "Have you enabled RGBA in the file output node properties? The output settings in the render/output panel are overridden by the file output node settings." ([source](https://blenderartists.org/t/file-output-node-will-not-embed-alpha-into-1-png/586252))

Comment: Thank you both for answering so quickly.  Yes I've watched both those videos and many RBGA the same as output properties output, If I Tick the tickbox "Use Alpha"  in the viewer node, I see the output I would like, but if I render it I get the same output as if the tickbox was unticked.

Comment: Have u tried connecting your keying node to the composite node?

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried the composite node and if "Use Alpha is ticked it gives me what I want, but when I render it still has the green background rather than the alpha. Is it possible to render out an image sequence with an alpha background in Blender?

Comment: Can you add the image of your render with the composite node ? Also try using the transparent in the film tab .

Comment: Yes, if I use the composite node it views perfectly in the "Image Editor", but when I try to render a frame it still has the green background. If I move the Alpha slider the green disappears again in the Image viewer but will change back to green when I try to render it.

Comment: I've also added a background image but when I render it, it still has the green background instead of the image. I had transparent ticked in the film tab.

Comment: I tried my self and is working correctly. Probably a bug. Another thing that i noticed on your screen is that you have 2.83.0, try it with the newest 2.83.3

Comment: Thanks Emir, I will try that now..

Comment: Thanks again, I just tried Blender 2.83.3 and still had the same problem. Then I was just trying random things and I found in the Post Processing options of Output Properties that un-ticking sequencer made it render properly. I thank you all again for your time and I apologise for my lack of knowledge.